# Streamlines on a triangulation with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I made a triangulation object in matplotlib (out of the P matrix, which contains points coordinates, and the T matrix, which contains the triangles nodes, that describe a rectangle minus a hole) and computed some scalar field called *phi* at the nodes of this triangulation (using a finite element method applied to a Poisson equation). Using this triangulation I compute the gradient, which is what I am interested in. I made a *quiver* plot of this vector field, everything is nice, the vectors don't intersect with the hole.

However, when I want to plot streamlines via the *streamplot* function, they intersect the hole, like in the following figure:

[image]

The thing is, in order to trace streamlines, I have to create a structured grid for the *streamplot* function. But since my vector field is not defined at the nodes of the regular grid, I need to interpolate the values at these nodes. For that I used *griddata*. The problem is, in doing so, the hole is covered by the regular grid so the vector field becomes defined inside the hole, hence the result. Here is the relevant piece of code that produced the picture:

```
def plot_streamlines(P, T, phi):
    triangulation = tr.Triangulation(P[:,0], P[:,1], T)
    interpolator = tr.CubicTriInterpolator(triangulation, phi)
    (u_x,u_y) = interpolator.gradient(triangulation.x, triangulation.y)
    grid_x, grid_y = np.mgrid[x_min:x_max:100j, y_min:y_max:100j]
    grid_u_x = ip.griddata(P, u_x, (grid_x,grid_y), method='cubic')
    grid_u_y = ip.griddata(P, u_y, (grid_x,grid_y), method='cubic')
    pl.streamplot(grid_x[:,0], grid_y[0,:], -grid_u_x.T, -grid_u_y.T)
```

I am aware of *masked arrays* but didn't manage to use the mask to get the result I wanted. I wanted to create a kind of masked regulard grid and then interpolate the vector field on it, but I didn't manage to do it. Does somebody has experience with this kind of problem? Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't it be enough to draw a filled white circle *over* the streamlines?

Comment: @hitzg: I think the problem is that the interpolation with griddata also takes place inside the disk (but shouldn't), so if I fill the circle (or if I mask the gradient like I did before) I won't display the right streamlines.

Comment: Do you have a canonical test case to check the streamlines outside the disk against?

Comment: @cphlewis: No I don't but I really think the problem comes from the interpolation, not the streamplot function. For instance, when I plot the length of the vector field on the regular grid (before calling streamplot), the disk has been filled with values, whereas it should have been something like NaN. I definitely have to find a way to interpolate the values of the vector field at only some part of the regular grid (the rectangle minus the disk).

Comment: I was wondering how you were positive you had an error. The image you show is definitely "conscious" of the disk -- why do you think you can't just draw a filled white circle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code sample `interpolator.gradient`is already an interpolator i.e. you do not need to use it in combination with `griddata`. Try:

```
grid_u_x, grid_u_y = interpolator.gradient(grid_x, grid_y)
```

As this interpolator is aware of your triangulation mesh, it should result is a velocity vector filled of `nan` outside your mesh. `Streamplot` should hopefully be able to handle this gracefully as in this example:

http://matplotlib.org/examples/images_contours_and_fields/streamplot_demo_masking.html