# Streamplot on triangulations without grid interpolation?

Tags: python, matplotlib, triangulation, streamline

`matplotlib` provides `contour` and `tricontour` functions for drawing contours for scalar data respectively on regular grids and on triangulations. It also provides the `streamplot` function for drawing streamlines for vector data on regular grids but it does not seem to provide an equivalent for data on triangulations while this is a common case for instance in FEM simulations. Is there a way to plot streamlines for vector data on triangulations without going through grid interpolation (as `tricontour` does relatively to `contour`), which would introduce unnecessary approximations and masks for dealing with irregular boundaries?

I was not able so far to find such a functionality, even outside of `matplotlib`.

Answer (score 0):

The interpolation for the streamlines has to happen somewhere.  It is easy to extrapolate where a particle in motion would end up in a regular grid, but for a triangulated mesh, extrapolating the motion to identify which triangle contains the extrapolated particle is expensive.

Maybe [Streamlines on a triangulation with matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30786274/streamlines-on-a-triangulation-with-matplotlib?rq=2) would help?

Comment: That might be expensive too for tricontour. Yet it is offered. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Contours are cheaper since they only go from edge to edge within each triangle, making them easily vectorizable, contrary to particle tracking and streamlines which have to extrapolate across multiple triangles.  Particle tracking and streamlines need to identify the adjacent triangles, while contouring does not.

Comment: OK thanks but, even slower, streamlines on triangulations would be useful.